# params.get() returns array and string for checkbox

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a checkbox on my page. I realize when I do a params.get() on the checkbox, it returns an array if multiple values are chosen or just a string with that one value. 
Below is `println params` for when I choose three values vs when I choose just one:

```
list = [21, 22, 62]
list = 21
```

If i assign this to a variable (using def list =), first one is an array, second a string. If I use String[] , i get the first array alright, but the second comes as [2,1] messing up my logic.

```
String[] list = params.get("list") // list [21, 22, 62]
String[] list = params.get("list") // list [2,1] (21 was chosen)
```

I am stumped by this.

I could build hacks to manage this but is there a cleaner way or something i don't know or understand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is a cleaner way. Always use `params.list("list")`. This will always return a list.

`[21, 22, 23]` or `[21]` (with one selection)